# Elimination of infinitesimals

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the following proposition:

> Given:
>
> a set $A ⊆ ℝ$,
>
> a limit point $p ∈ ℝ ∪ \{-∞,∞\}$ of $A$,
>
> functions $f, f_1, g, g_1 : A → ℝ$.
>
> If $f, g ≠ 0$ in a deleted neighborhood of $p$, $lim_{x→p}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = ℓ$, $f_1(x) = o(f(x))$, and $g_1(x) = o(g(x))$, then $lim_{x→p}\frac{f(x)+f_1(x)}{g(x)+g_1(x)} = ℓ$.
>
> $Proof.$
> We can restrict all the functions to a set $A' = A∩\{J-p\}$, with $J$ neighborhood of p, such that $f, g, (g+g_1) ≠ 0$ on $A'$, without altering the limits. Then
> $$lim_{x→p}\frac{f(x)+f_1(x)}{g(x)+g_1(x)} = lim_{x→p}\frac{f(x)(1+\frac{f_1(x)}{f(x)})}{g(x)(1+\frac{g_1(x)}{g(x)})} =$$ $$ ℓ ⋅ \frac{1+ lim_{x→p}\frac{f_1(x)}{f(x)}}{1 + lim_{x→p}\frac{g1(x)}{g(x)}} = ℓ.$$

This may sound like a superfluous question, but is the hypothesis $f ≠ 0$ really necessary? It's used in the proof to allows division by $f(x)$, but the limits $lim_{x→p}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ and $lim_{x→p}\frac{f(x)+f_1(x)}{g(x)+g_1(x)} = ℓ$ could exist even if $f(x) = 0$ in at least a point $x$ in every neighborhood of $p$.

Comment: What is $o(f(x)$?

Comment: @Floris Claassens it's Landau symbol, it means ∀ ε > 0 ∃ I neighborhood of p, such that x ∈ A∩(I-{p}) ⇒ f1(x) < εf(x).

Comment: But what is $o(f(x))$ if $f$ is zero, since the question is whether $f \ne 0$ is necessary...

Comment: @GEdgar I suppose some f1(x) such that f1(x) = 0 if f(x) = 0 and f1(x) is closer to 0 than f(x) otherwise. E.g. p = 0, f(x) = dirichlet function, xf(x) = o(f(x)).